# Problem with Debugging in C++ Builder 2009

Tags: debugging, exception, c++builder, codeguard

I have a strange problem, I hope you can help me.

I write a program in C++ Builder 2009, when I run the program without debugger I see an Exception raised. bun in debugger never exception raised and I cant find the exception point.

And Also I enable the CodeGaurd in C++ for Finding the problem but the Exception never raised, If I disable codeGuard the exception will be here again.

I use OpenCV and some Delphi units in the program.
And when I compile it I see more than 2 millions of code line compiled.

Thanks in advance for your attentoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things too look at:

1. in the IDE options, make sure you are not ignoring some exceptions
2. debug builds MAY have memory variables set to NULL on run, release builds will not. Make sure you are running the same build (Debug) in both the IDE and without.

Ignore the line count that is displayed, its all those .hpp files that holds the vcl headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yes I check the Initialization of Pointers.